# Impossible to "ng-disabled" a button submit, what should we know that may get in the way?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, file-upload, bootstrap-table, disabled-input

I have a very basic form in which is an input to upload a file (xlsx in that case) just like so :

```
<input type="file" data-file="import" name="xlfile" id="xlf" />
```

In the whole application, I have many forms, way more complexe than this one, and not having this issue at all. Main difference is they don't have an upload input, so that maybe related to that.

Upon selecting a file, there are several  functions that get called, to read the file, check that some info is correct, and display a report as well as the file's content in a bootstrap-table below.

Everything is in a modal window, and at the very end of it, sits a single **button type submit** with an ng-click directive to launch another function ...

I have been unable to get this button disabled with **ng-disable** directive and finally resigned to make it disable per default by adding the attribute **disabled** in the html tag.

Down in the javascript code, i have this line executing in the case that everything's okay :

```
document.querySelector('#myButtonId').removeAttribute('disabled')
```

My problem is now to figure out what kind of magic is going on here !? :-)

--

Here is my first attempt button :

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="doThat()" ng-disabled="isItOkay">IMPORT</button>
```

Where "isItOkay" would take false as value, at the beginning of the controller and true whenever requirements would be met (which is happening after file check pass if nothing wrong happened after several function calls, among which jquery and angular are working (checked in chrome source tab).

A second attempt was to replace the variable by a function after reading some esoteric explanations about behavior of boolean values in ng-directives...

```
<button type="submit" ... ng-disabled="isItOkay()">...</button>
```

Where the function would return true or false.

After that, I've also tried other type of values like numbers, or strings ... checking if result was greater than ... etc ... in order to see if types of value had something to do, but nothing worked.

When exploring the code in the chrome "source" tab, I've noticed that the "isItOkay" variable sometimes wasn't even defined, and most of the time wasn't accessible while code was stopped with bookmarks in the relevant part of the code.

This conducted me to think about a possible isolated scope, but I'm still not knowledgeable enough about angularJS to figure out what's going wrong.

I'm sorry if I don't put the code here, it's rather huge, and wouldn't help at best. But feel free to ask if it's really necessary.

So my question to end this long post:

#### *What do we need to know about values passed into ng-disabled, that would eventually prevent the code from doing what is reasonably expected at first ?*

Answer (score 0):

It is `ng-disabled` not `ng-disable`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: Simple typo here, it was disabled in the code but thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try with a dot (.). Say in your controller, you would have something like:

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.controller(['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.flags = {
        isItOkey: false
      };
    }
  ]);

})();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="flags.isItOkey" />Is It Okey?
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <button type="button" ng-disabled="!flags.isItOkey">Okey</button>
  <button type="button" ng-disabled="flags.isItOkey">Not Okey</button>

  {{flags|json}}
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I Will try that

Comment: Something interesting happened, though it did not fix the problem.
At first attempt , I put ng-disabled="flags.isItOkay".
But the value was false and so the button couldn't be disabled, but I found flags.isItOkay in the scope.

When i added a ! like so : ng-disabled="!flags.isItOkay", the flags object was no longer in the scope ...

Comment: I just updated the code with falsy case. Seems to be working in the example code. Not sure what breaks in your code. May be include a running snippet in your question, so that i can see what goes on exactly.

Comment: Another update to correct the button state with flags, just semantics.

Comment: I thank you for your help. Sadly , this really is what I'm doing in other forms, where code is working as expected. ----- I must have a conflict occurring in the functions or something even worse but I don't have the right to place samples here ...